# Sum of an average Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-xi

For each "Job Number" group there are multiple "Quantity" records. I only require one "Quantity" record per "Job Number", so I have tried to achieve this by using an Average of the "Quantity". This works in isolation at Group Level, however I need to then show an average of "Quantity" at a higher group level

For example, Job Number 100000 has 4 records in the detail level with a Quantity of 5000 for each record, Job Number 100001 has 2 records in the detail level with a Quantity of 2000 for each record

Using the average function, the group level shows Job Number 100000 with one quantity record of 5000 and Job Number 100001 with one quantity record of 2000

At the higher group level, the average should be 3,500 (7,000 / 2) but it actually displays as 4,000 (24,000 / 6)

The formula should be a Sum of the Average Quantity / Distinct Count of Job Number

For the life of me I can't get this to work

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had tried this already but I could not summarize the field. I finally found a way around this by declaring a variable and then resetting on the change of group

Answer (score 1):

Create a Running Total and set the evaluate condition to 'On Change of Group':

[image]